# How can I determine what font faces are available for me to use with Sublime Text 3?

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, sublime-text-3, font-faces

I would like to change the font face in Sublime Text.

How can I see what options are available for me to change it to?

Comment: Sublime Text can use the same fonts as on your OS

Comment: Great.  How can I determine what fonts are available on my OS, which is Mac - Mavericks, incidentally.

Comment: Answering my own question - on Mac, use the Font Book app.

Answer (score 6):

From your Finder, open *Applications » Font Book.app*. It will show you a list of all fonts installed on your system:

[image]

You can use all of these in Sublime Text (however you may want try only Fixed Width fonts for coding) by adding this in your preferences – just substitute the name of the font:

```
{
  "font_face": "Source Code Pro"
}
```

---

#### Font Variants

*(based on a suggested edit by @Merlin)*

If you want to choose font variants, this becomes more complicated. An example (Sublime Text 3, macOS).

- Font name in Font Book: `Input Mono Compressed Extra Light Italic`
- Font filename: `InputMonoCompressed-ExtraLightItalic.ttf`

In your settings, you then have to use:

```
"font_face": "InputMonoCompressed-ExtraLightItalic",
```

That is, go with the filename minus extension.

The following works for "Input Mono Compressed Extra Light":

```
  "font_face": "InputMonoCompressed ExLight",
```

The following attempts didn't work:

```
  "font_face": "Input Mono Compressed Extra Light Italic",
  "font_face": "InputMonoCompressed ExtraLightItalic",
  "font_face": "InputMonoCompressedExtraLightItalic",
  "font_face": "InputMonoCompressed ExLightItalic",
  // and more permutations
  "font_face": "Input Mono Compressed ExLight",
```

Which is a little maddening considering `Input Mono Compressed` did work for the non-'Extra Light' version. I never did discover the right permutations and shortening to get the Extra Light Italic to work.

Comment: What syntax allows you to specify Regular, ExtraLight, etc.?

Comment: @Merlin Apparently not possible: https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/request-monospace-font-family-typeface-variants/34038

Comment: I experimented with typing exactly as shown in fontbook, with spaces between words removed. This worked for example: ‘InputMonoCondensed ExtraLight’. The spacing or lack of was important, but chars were all from Font Book name.

Comment: Good to know, @Merlin! Feel free to suggest an edit to the answer to reflect that.

Comment: @Merlin Your initial edit was rejected, but I took parts of it and reordered it to put the actual answer on top.